# Problem using miniDisplay port adapter to VGA on Dell XPS l502x

Tags: 11.10, nvidia-optimus, external-monitor, xps, adapter

It's my first question here and I feel really bothered by this problem. I recently bought a new AOC e2343F2k 23" monitor, it supports 1920x1080 resolution and when I plugged by the first time, it worked perfectly.

I made some changes (I do not recall what), and I can no longer get full hd resolution, the best I can get is 1440x900.

I tried to install another different distros in order to check if the source problem is the os, but no success. I don't know what to do. I forced the resolution using xrandr but it also did not work, the screen resolution is expanded beyond the monitor edges and I can't see the right and left side of the desktop and the screen image quality is poor.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: It's a cable issue eventually (Poor quality miniDP to VGA adapters). You're not the only one having this issue.
You need a good quality adapter that preserve didigtal signal quality and properties when converting into analog signal. Generally, if you got a 20 bucks cable, it wouldn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

According to Hanynowsky, this is a hardware issue, which should be solved by replacing the cable. (If that is correct, then this answers the question and solves the problem.)

> It's a cable issue eventually (Poor quality miniDP to VGA adapters).
>   You're not the only one having this issue. You need a good quality
>   adapter that preserve didigtal signal quality and properties when
>   converting into analog signal. Generally, if you got a 20 bucks cable,
>   it wouldn't do the job.

– [Hanynowsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/20496/hanynowsky) [Apr 8 '12 at 23:34](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108111/problem-using-minidisplay-port-adapter-to-vga-on-dell-xps-l502x#comment143032_108111)